Flutter tabbar any way to curve underline and bring it top
I'm using tabbar and would like to design something like this.

Is it possible to do this with some functionality of tabbar?
or can I achieve this with child of Tab?
I'm not here asking for whole code but would like to know what information i should look for to achieve this.


Container(
              height: kToolbarHeight + 8.0,
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, right: 16.0, left: 16.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: _selectedColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(8.0)),
              ),
              child: TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(8.0)),
                    color: Colors.white),
                labelColor: Colors.black,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                tabs: _tabs,
              ),
            ),

is this the one you asked try this
